# Access component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have this code, and I want to access the states of the `Die` component. How can I do it?

EDIT:
I have the `Die` class (component), and I want to access it's `setImage` state function. 
Let me put it another way: How can I access **ANY** value of the child component from the parent component?

```
function App() {
    const Roll = () => {
        console.log(dice[0].props.Die);
    };
    const dice = [<Die />, <Die />, <Die />, <Die />, <Die />];

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="dice">{dice}</div>
            <button className="generate" onClick={Roll}>
                Roll
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: from where you want to access it?

Comment: you should use state management library like reduxjs

Comment: from the code mentioned.

Comment: Please explain more about question, like what you want to perform after accessing the component

Comment: You CAN'T, the React data-flow is designed as a waterfall, props passed from parent to child, and state is only been held inside the local component. You can `lift-state-up` but it means expose child component's API to parent, which means those thing is no longer belongs to the child anymore.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: You could use `useRef()` hook to ref each `< Die / >` component, then manipulate function of those components, check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use useRef hook https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

a basic example is

```js
export default function App() {

  const dieRef = React.useRef(null);

  const Roll = () => {
    console.log(dieRef.current);
  };

  const dice = [
    <Die ref={dieRef} />,
    <Die />,
    <Die />,
    <Die />,
    <Die />
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="dice">{dice}</div>
      <button className="generate" onClick={Roll}>
        Roll
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but for your code example should be something like this

```js
export default function App() {
  const arrOfDieRef = [
    React.useRef(null),
    React.useRef(null),
    React.useRef(null),
    React.useRef(null),
    React.useRef(null)
  ];

  const Roll = () => {
    console.log(arrOfDieRef[0].current.state);
    console.log(arrOfDieRef[1].current.state);
    console.log(arrOfDieRef[2].current.state);
    console.log(arrOfDieRef[3].current.state);
    console.log(arrOfDieRef[4].current.state);
  };

  const dice = [
    <Die ref={arrOfDieRef[0]} />,
    <Die ref={arrOfDieRef[1]} />,
    <Die ref={arrOfDieRef[2]} />,
    <Die ref={arrOfDieRef[3]} />,
    <Die ref={arrOfDieRef[4]} />
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="dice">{dice}</div>
      <button className="generate" onClick={Roll}>
        Roll
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `Warning: Function components cannot be given refs.`

Answer (score -1):

You can use React hooks like UseContext and CreateContext for state management and to access component state anywhere in project.

You can also use Redux for State Management